# Como impedir que o usuário digite no EditText, mas permitir que ao clicar nele abra um DatePicker?

Tags: android, edittext

Tenho um EditText que ao clicar nele abre um DatePicker, como impedir que o usuario digite no EditText? tentei usar edtData.setEnable(false) mas ao clicar no editText não acontece nada.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione ao EditText o seguinte:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Isso irá impedir que o EditText receba o *focus*, não permitindo que seja possível digitar nele.

Em alternativa use um TextView em vez do EditText.

Para que o TextView tenha a aparência de um EditText use:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
```

Comment: valeu, era exatamente o que queria.

Comment: Muito boa solução

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar a edição no EditText defina KeyListener como null

```
edtData.setKeyListener(null);
```

Comment: Isso não funciona.

Comment: Tens razão, obrigado, havia digitado errado, acabei de corrigir minha resposta, abraços

Comment: Isso sim, já funciona e é uma solução interessante.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin

```
myEditText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

Exemplo de extension:

```
fun EditText.hideKeyBoardFocus() {
    this.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
    this.addTextChangedListener {
        if (it?.isNotEmpty() == true){
            this.setText("")
        }
    }
}
```